gsola2.isioma2:drawable/splashscreen_logo) not found. error: failed linking references. React-native Expo
I am working on React-native with Expo, and each time I try to build my AAB I get this error, I have tried multiple things but the error persists, does anyone know the actual cause of this problem and how to fix it. for all that I know the splash image is present in my code, and it's showing locally when I open the app, so I don't know why it's a problem when building for production.
/home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml Warning:
provider<#695411232856997969>.modules.filesystem.FileSystemFileProvider@android:authorities was tagged at AndroidManifest.xml:0 to replace other declarations but no other declaration present

Task :app:processReleaseManifest
Task :app:processApplicationManifestReleaseForBundle
Task :app:checkReleaseAarMetadata
Task :app:packageReleaseResources
Task :app:parseReleaseLocalResources
Task :app:processReleaseManifestForPackage
Task :react-native-screens:configureCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
Task :app:processReleaseResources FAILED
Task :react-native-screens:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
Task :expo-modules-core:buildCMakeRelWithDebInfo[arm64-v8a]
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.


What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processReleaseResources'.


A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
Android resource linking failed
ERROR: /home/expo/workingdir/build/android/app/src/main/res/drawable/ic_launcher_background.xml:4: AAPT: error: resource drawable/splashscreen_logo (aka com.kingsola2.isioma2:drawable/splashscreen_logo) not found.

i have been getting this error mesage whenever i try to build my expo app for android but unfortunately i don't know how to fix it, i have tried
[![This is the error][1]][1]
app.json
  "expo": {
    "name": "isioma3",
    "slug": "isioma3",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "newArchEnabled": true,
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash-icon.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "package": "com.kingsola2.isioma3"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    },
    "extra": {
      "eas": {
        "projectId": "e2b576"
      }
    },
    "owner": "kingsola2"
  }
}


eas.json
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 13.2.3",
    "appVersionSource": "remote"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "autoIncrement": true
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}

full error message on expo
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask$TaskAction
> Android resource linking failed
     com.kingsola2.isioma2.app-mergeReleaseResources-58:/values/values.xml:5738: error: resource drawable/splashscreen_logo (aka com.kingsola2.isioma2:drawable/splashscreen_logo) not found.
     com.kingsola2.isioma2.app-mergeReleaseResources-58:/values/values.xml:5738: error: resource drawable/splashscreen_logo (aka com.kingsola2.isioma2:drawable/splashscreen_logo) not found.
     error: failed linking references.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 12s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.10.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
429 actionable tasks: 429 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.```

if I create a new react-expo app it builds successfully, but if I make changes on the app, mostly the app.json file, that is when I get this message, and even if I revert the code to it's original state the error persists 


  [1]: https://i.sstatic.net/Y51t0Yx7.png


Are you on SDK 52? I had the same issue after upgrading from SDK 51. The issue is that using splash screen now requires to using the plugin configuration (not the expo.splash key at the root of your app.json) and if such plugin configuration is not present, expo will use expo.splash key to form an equivalent plugin configuration but if there is no expo.splash key present (or some properties are missing) this process will fail.
I do think it's a bug since now is mandatory to have a splash screen an there was no such requirement on SDK51 and below. Anyway, migrating this config:
"expo": {
  ...
  "splash": {
    "image": "./assets/splash-icon.png",
    "resizeMode": "contain",
    "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
  },
  ...
}

to this should fix the issue (remove expo.splash)
"expo": {
  ...
  "plugins": [
    [
      "expo-splash-screen",
      {
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff",
        "image": "./assets/splash-icon.png",
      }
    ]
  ]
}

It did it an my issue was gone. If you still are having this issue on SDK 52 refer to the splash screen docs and this github issue
Also, check the SDK 52 release notes as it mentions some breaking changes between 51 and 52 (even though they are not stated as breaking changes, such as the splash screen)
